# How to build a csproj file using .net 2.0 MSBuild programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, msbuild, mono

I am using unity so I have to stick with .net 2.0. I have copied the following files from the following path to my Assets/Editor folder

> Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\
>
> Microsoft.Build.Engine.dll
>
> Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll
>
> Microsoft.Build.Tasks.dll
>
> Microsoft.Build.Utilities.dll

I tried to figure out my self how to do it, but most examples on the web uses newer MSBuild version, mostly MSBuild 4.0 and up.

I tried the following code, but the msBuild.BuildEngine is null.

```
MSBuild msBuild = new MSBuild ();
msBuild.BuildEngine.BuildProjectFile (csproj, new string[] { "Release" }, new Dictionary<string, string> (), new Dictionary<string, string> ());
msBuild.Execute ();
```

Comment: If your goal is to use Visual Studio with Unity you can just use Visual Studio tools for unity: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dn940019.aspx

Comment: @tweetypi Thanks but that's not the goal. I want to dynamically build a related csproj needed by my game. That way I will not have to build my csproj then build my game, and it will be a streamlined process.

Comment: With Unity 2017, you can enable support for .NET 4.6+C# 6. Go to Edit->Project Settings->Player and set Other Settings->Scripting Runtime Version.

Comment: @DavidOliver Exactly, I tried and it worked. But it's experimental and I am doing the game in a production environment, so that's not an option for now.

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating the `MSBuild` task which is meant to be used from within a buildscript. In that context it gets the Engine from the host, most often the MSBuild executable.

You're looking for the [`Engine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.engine(v=vs.90).aspx) class that is found in the `Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine` namespace and sits in the assembly Microsoft.Build.Engine.dll .

The following Demo Console application shows how you can use that class. I've created a class `MyBuild` that has all the logic to create the Engine and build a projectfile.

```
class MyBuild
{
    string _proj;
    string _target;
    bool _result;

    public MyBuild(string proj, string target)
    {
        _proj = proj;
        _target= target;
    }

    public bool Result {get{return _result;}}

    public void Start() 
    {
        Engine engine = new Engine();
        engine.RegisterLogger(new ConsoleLogger());
        _result = engine.BuildProjectFile(_proj, _target);
    }
}
```

In the Main method we set things up. Notice that it also creates a Thread and sets its ApparatmentState to STA. In my testing I found no issues when *not* doing that but the warning was rather persistent so I assume there are scenario's where it might break if not run from such thread. Better safe then sorry.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine;

public static void Main()
{
    string proj= @"yourprogram.csproj";
    string target = "Build";

    MyBuild mybuild = new MyBuild(proj, target);

    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mybuild.Start));
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
    t.Join();

    if (mybuild.Result) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed!");
    }
}
```

To build above code you have to reference both the Engine.dll as the Framework.dll.

> csc program.cs  /r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Build.Engine.dll /r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll